# How to divide array in to groups with smallest sum difference?

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have array of integers, I need to sort them in unknown number of groups with minimal difference in sum of each group.

example:

```
Array: 2, 1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 6, 8
Number of groups = 3
Result:
Group 1 – 8, 2 = 10
Group 2 – 7, 2, 1 = 10
Group 3 – 6, 4, 1 = 11
```

Is there any alghoritham too solve this problem?
I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if the number of groups is 2 this reduces to the subset sum problem variant the partition problem.  This proves the problem is NP-hard, so you shouldn't try to find an efficient algorithm.

Given that it will be at least exponential you might as well just generate all permutations and pick the best.  I know some people don't like recursion, but it really is useful here for enumerating the group possibilities:

```
recfunc(array, groups):
    if array is empty
        return an array containing the element groups
    else
        groupsList = empty array
        foreach aGroup in groups
            element = array[0]
            groupsList += recfun(array - element, groups where aGroup adds element)
       return groupsList
```

This algorithm will create a list of all possibilities.  It is fairly inefficient, but shouldn't be too hard for you to implement.  From here just go through the list and calculate if the sum of the groups is the minimum of the list.